# How do you get a sum() twice from one table with different where clause?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    sum(qty) as accept,
    (SELECT sum(qty) 
     FROM pile 
     WHERE pf=false) as reject 
FROM pile 
WHERE pf=true;
```

That's the SQL I use currently, but I'm guessing its not best practice?
The other alternative I used before was  `SELECT sum(qty) FROM pile GROUP BY pf` but I need them as columns and not as rows.

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Single pass through the table.

```
SELECT 
    sum(CASE WHEN pf = TRUE THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as accept,
    sum(CASE WHEN pf = FALSE THEN qty ELSE 0 END) as reject
FROM pile;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT pileTrue.sumTrue as accept, pileFalse.sumFalse as reject
FROM
(SELECT sum(qty) sumFalse FROM pile WHERE pf=false) as pileFalse,
(SELECT sum(qty) sumTrue  FROM pile WHERE pf=true ) as pileTrue
```

Answer (score 1):

Not any better, but more readable IMO.

```
SELECT
accept = (SELECT sum(qty) FROM pile WHERE pf = true),
reject = (SELECT sum(qty) FROM pile WHERE pf = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  check it



  select max(accept), max(v2 ) 
    from
    (
              SELECT 
                    sum(qty) as accept,null v2  
                FROM pile 
                WHERE pf=true
                union
                 SELECT null accept,sum(qty) v2  
                     FROM pile 
                     WHERE pf=false
    )
    group by accept,v2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(qty)
          FROM pile
         WHERE pf = true) AS accept,
       (SELECT SUM(qty)
          FROM pile
         WHERE pf = false) AS reject
```